# How do you stay motivated during the job search process?

Tags: job-search, career-development, motivation

I've been starting up the job search again, and forgot how tiring it can be.

If you consider the time it takes to think about what you are looking for, to research companies, prepare your resume/cover letter, and then actually reaching out to company representatives its overwhelming. Not to mention the fact that I currently have a full time job!

I'm curious how people stay motivated during the job search process even when you feel like it's taking longer than it should and getting more rejections than you expected?

Comment: Just keep in mind that jobs don't grow in trees, so it is usual to spend some time searching for them. Even more if you are not searching for jobs all the time, as you are currently working full time.

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: Build your linkedin network.

Answer (score 12):

I was unemployed for a year or more several times so I understand how frustrating and depressing it can be.

Just remember that you **will** get a job. You will. It's inevitable. Yes, it's tiring but so is working.

My father-in-law has a saying. When you don't have a job, **finding a job *is* your job.**

And that's how I approach it.  I treat it like a job.

1. Get up early every morning and get dressed for work.
2. Make a list of tasks each day and do them, just like a paying job.
3. Literally treat it like a job. It takes discipline, but don't slack off just because you're at home. If it helps to do some of your search at a library, do that.
4. Keep up on your work skills or learn new ones. That will help you feel productive as well.
5. Exercise if you can and make sure you get outside at least once every day.  You need to avoid depression and these will help.
6. Network, Network, Network, physically if possible. If there are Meetup groups where you can network, do that. Just include networking in your job search activities so you can be around people. That will help you stay positive.
7. Remember that not getting a positive response isn't a rejection but just you finding out another place that you don't want to work anyway because it obviously isn't a good fit. **They're not rejecting you**, they're doing a favor and enabling you to find someplace that will appreciate you.

I wish you the best and remember what I said above. You will get a job. The key is to not give up. Something will come.

Comment: This is rock solid advice.  exactly the same approach I have taken in the past.  Definitely do NOT SKIP items one and two.

Answer (score 0):

If a company rejects you, even when you're clearly qualified for the role, it can always say something about the company itself. *"You passed the technical test, are excellently qualified, seemed like a nice person, but we're going to go in another direction..."* What!? Of course it's important to acknowledge any personal shortcomings if an interview doesn't work out, but also look at what their feedback, or even lack thereof, can say about the company. It may be a blessing in disguise. (Yes I know they may just have had a slightly better candidate, but this can help with the fatigue that comes from too many interviews that didn't work out)

Primarily, I would suggest reaching out to some recruitment agencies, ideally ones that are specialists in your field and where you can have a direct line to the recruiter who reads your CV. It's their job to find your strengths and get you a job suited to that. Their own job and reputation depends on it! They will have established connections and can work to make you stand out better. They will help you find companies that don't openly advertise vacancies, and of course help identify your own best qualities. As an added bonus, they can job hunt while you're stuck doing other things!

Remember, it's a question of WHEN you get a job, not IF.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in response to your question about staying motivated:

<sup>This answer is based upon my long-time thoughts about job interviews, but I think it can be expanded to the process of researching potential new employers as well.</sup>

Try to approach thinking about job searching as furthering your knowledge about the field you work in. In every interview I have ever attended, the interviewer has asked me a question that made me think a little differently about what I am used to considering the standard responsibilities that go with my job description.  Maybe they asked me about supervising other staff members, and I have never been in the role of supervisor before--well, now I know that at some firms my job title includes supervisory responsibilities, and it is important for me to begin thinking about how I will learn/develop this skill. They might ask you a question about how you would solve a problem that makes you realize that they use completely different processes than your current or previous employers. Now you have a new skill that you can begin learning about that will make you a stronger candidate for future opportunities.

Questions like that can give you a tremendous insight into the way different companies function--and could potentially spark ideas for ways you might improve the processes you use at your current job.

It's a little more difficult to tease this type of information out of a company website, but I still think that, as you review and research potential employers, you can try to think about how what you learn from their websites can enhance your understanding of your industry.  Maybe they offer services that your current firm does not offer--think about how those services might be related to or combine in productive ways with the services you expected.

Job hunting is never a fun process--but for me, using it as an opportunity to increase my knowledge and understanding of my chosen industry gives me an extra boost of energy that helps me move past those feelings of disappointment that occur when what I think is the perfect company for me doesn't even respond to my cover letter and resume.